# Check the specific number of occurrences of a single character in a string with regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to create a regex pattern for my powershell code. I've never worked with regex before, so I'm a total noob.

The regex should check if there are two points in the string.

Examples that SHOULD work:

```
3.1.1
5.10.12
10.1.15
```

Examples that SHOULD NOT work:

```
3
3.1
5.10.12.1
```

The string must have two points in it, the number of digits doesn't matter.

I've tried something like this, but it doesn't really work and I think its far from the right solution...

```
([\d]*.[\d]*.[\d])
```

Comment: Since the number of numbers doesn't matter, would, `..` match?

Comment: Are you extracting those substrings or just check if a string follows the `#+.#+.#+` format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current regex I think you could escape the dot `\.` or else the dot would match any character.

You could add anchors for the start `^` and the end `$` of the string and update your regex to [`^\d*\.\d*\.\d*$`](https://regex101.com/r/EHGgYy/3)
That would also match `..4` and `..`

Or if you want to match one or more digits, I think you could use [`^\d+(?:\.\d+){2}$`](https://regex101.com/r/EHGgYy/1)

That would match

```
^       # From the beginning of the string
\d+     # Match one or more digits
(?:     # Non capturing group
  \.\d+ # Match a dot and one or more ditits
){2}    # Close non capturing group and repeat 2 times
$       # The end of the string
```

Comment: Thanks, this did it for me! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a lookahead:

```
^\d(?=(?:[^.]*\.[^.]*){2}$)[\d.]*$
```

---

Broken down, this says:

```
^                       # start of the line
\d                      # at least one digit
(?=                     # start of lookahead
    (?:[^.]*\.[^.]*){2} # not a dot, a dot, not a dot - twice
$                       # anchor it to the end of the string
)
[\d.]*                  # only digits and dots, 0+ times
$                       # the end of the string
```

---

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/FEhvxc/1/).